# How to Switch Threads

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading

I have 2 threads. I need to switch between them by pressing a key.

```
Thread outputplayer = new Thread(PlayerOutput);
Thread outputplaylist = new Thread(PlaylistOutput);


outputplayer.Start(player);
outputplaylist.Start(player);
outputplaylist.Suspend();


        while (true)
        {
            if (changePlaylist)
            {
                if (playlist)
                {
                    changePlaylist = false;

                    outputplaylist.Resume();
                    outputplayer.Suspend();
                }
                else
                {
                    changePlaylist = false;

                    outputplayer.Resume();
                    outputplaylist.Suspend();
                }
            }
            HandleInput(player);
        }
```

I tried this, but it doesnt switch always.


When I press a key, first thread should stop/pause and second thread should start execute. When I press key again, second thread should stop/pause and first thread should start execute. And so on. 1 => 2 => 1 => 2 ... 


What should I do?

Comment: Whatever you are doing, you won't achive it this way.  Please explain what are you in fact trying to do.

Comment: Doesn't this defeat the entire point of threading, namely doing two different things at once? Why not just use a single thread?

Comment: I think threads are better at this situation

Comment: This isn't what threads are for.

Comment: Why can not both threads run at the same time, are they sharing a variable between them and you are having trouble synchronizing access?

Comment: You could acheive something of what you're looking for by having a dedicated thread body for each thread and using a Semaphore to force one thread to block while the other executes. The executing thread could then signal the other thread to run when it decides it no longer should execute.  That being said, all the other posters are right: what you're currently doing above isn't what threads are for.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Do *not* ignore the Obsolete warnings on the Suspend and Resume methods.  They were obsoleted for this *exact* reason.  The exact place in code where they will freeze is completely unpredictable.  Quite bad news if that's inside a *lock* statement.   You've also created a time slot where *both* will be running.

Don't use threads for this.

Comment: Exactly: the answer is to have a different thread architecture, with one collecting input, and two others doing the tasks between you might want to switch processing/priority/etc.

Comment: There do not exist enough up-arrows for this answer.